Launching TB3 Cartographer causes map origin to be shifted in RVIZ
I am creating a multi-robot cartography and routing system using ROS2 Humble. When I launch each robot's nav stack, everything looks good. As soon as I launch the cartographer_ros node, the map on RVIZ appears to reposition itself such that the origin is moved to where the robot originally spawned. I believe it is related to tf or tf_static, but I have no idea how to solve this and I've been at it for a week. My final senior presentation is next week and this is the only bug we haven't been able to fix.
The images below depict RVIZ before and after launching the cartographer for reference. It is also worth noting that because I am attempting to run this with multiple robots, each robot has its own namespace.
 
UPDATE:
The multi-robot navigation scheme that we adapted from nav2_bringup's own multi-robot nav system remaps both /tf and /tf_static to the robot's namespace (i.e. robot_)/tf and robot_0/tf_static). This means that launching a static tranform publisher node is ineffective because everything in the nav stack and RVIZ is using the namespaced tf and tf_static topics.
# Map fully qualified names to relative ones so the node's namespace can be prepended.
# In case of the transforms (tf), currently, there doesn't seem to be a better alternative
# https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/32
# https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/30
# TODO(orduno) Substitute with `PushNodeRemapping`
#              https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/issues/56
remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'),
              ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')]

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the tf2_ros package does not support namespaced tf_static topics. I tried creating a StaticTransformBroadcaster node from within my source code which would modify the publisher in said node to work on the namespaced topic, but this doesn't seem to work. The node does not appear on my node list at all. (Note that the PoseManager class is something I wrote to work with poses, and I can confirm this works as intended).
      static_transform_node = rclpy.create_node(f'{self.rover_name}/static_transform_publisher')
      tf_broadcaster = StaticTransformBroadcaster(static_transform_node)
      tf_broadcaster.pub_tf = static_transform_node.create_publisher(TFMessage, f"{self.rover_name}/tf_static", qos)
      static_transform: TransformStamped = PoseManager.transform_from_pose_stamped(self.nav.initial_pose)
      static_transform.header.stamp = self.nav.get_clock().now().to_msg()
      static_transform.header.frame_id = 'map'
      static_transform.child_frame_id = 'odom'
      tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(static_transform)

UPDATE 2: Perhaps these errors are related.
[component_container_isolated-5] [WARN] [1712949707.397861865] [nav2_costmap_2d]: Robot is out of bounds of the costmap!
[rviz2-2] [ERROR] [1712949707.571957950] [rviz2]: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 5.137000, but only time 6.137000 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [base_scan] to frame [map]
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1712949707.841413436] [rover_0.global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 5.137 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[component_container_isolated-5] [ERROR] [1712949707.901907400] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 5.470000 but the earliest data is at time 6.137000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
UPDATE 3:
I figured out a hacky patch to this where I set the initial pose of the robot to the origin and then manually transform all the instructions I set to it in advance. It works fine for a bit until the costmaps both begin to distort and the robot appears to spasm in RVIZ (likely because it is struggling to determine its position). The more it travels around the map, the more it spasms on RVIZ and the more the local and global costmaps distort.

